# How do I configure Laravel 5.3 with Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, gulp, vue.js

Every time I `gulp watch`, I get this

```
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir-vue'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gulpfile.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

How do I configure Laravel 5.3 with Vue in a logical order?

I've already pulled in Vue with `npm install vue`

Tell me if I forgot something crucial to add to this question.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you done `npm install laravel-elixir-vue --save-dev`?

Comment: Oh, that did the job. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Generally if you're getting `Cannot find module` errors, it means you forgot to install something.

Comment: @JoeClay It triggered another problem though :/ My Vue is now just flickering whenever I refresh the site. I don't get to see actually Vue content.

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question on here (since it's a separate issue), including relevant parts of your code. Maybe include the Vue.js tag as well.